# How to clear the Shibboleth session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron, shibboleth

I created a web application using angularjs. I integrated Shibboleth for Authentication on my login controller.I know it is possible to clear the session by cookies concept.

I am creating a client application from my Web Application Using Electron Packager.To convert the Web Application to Client Application so i didn't use Cookies on my angularjs Development.

I am not much aware in Electron Packager.I dont know how to clear the session for Shibboleth Authentication

Please any one can help me !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the that Shibboleth SP is configured for at least local logout, you'd need to redirect to `/Shibboleth.sso/Logout`.

See https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPServiceLogout.

Comment: I tried this but it is not solved.Is there any other ways to hit the angularjs function from main.js(Electron). If it is possible to hit the angularjs method from electron ,I fixed the issue @john